# Why is python's format function working differently with single vs. double quotes?

Tags: python, string, formatting

My understanding was that in Python, single and double quotes are interchangeable.  I came across an error that is confusing me:

```
for i in range(0, 50):
    print('{%4s}'.format(i), end="")
```

The above code gives me a KeyError (using Python 3.4).

if I switch the quotes used with the format function string to double quotes, however:

```
for i in range(0, 50):
    print("{%4s}".format(i), end="")   # double quotes in format string
```

it works as expected.

Can someone help me understand what's happening here and why?

Comment: I get a `KeyError` both times, could not replicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not valid with either style of quotes; as you say, the quotes make no difference.

I'm not sure what you're expecting `%4s` to do, but it's not a valid specifier in the format mini-language. Are you trying to pad each number to four spaces? If so it should be:

```
print("{:4}".format(i), end="")
```

or just

```
print(format(i, "4"), end="")
```

Comment: Thanks.  For some reason the double quotes seemed to be giving me output as expected but when I changed it to single quotes I got the error.  I must have made some other mistake, though, because when I restarted everything and tried again, it started giving me an error regardless of which quotes were used.

Answer (score 0):

Do not try to mix both string modulo operator and the .format() function.

You could do one of these:

```
print("%4s" % i)
```

Or:

```
print(format(i, "4"), end="")
```

The second looks cleaner, I would prefer that.